# Find f(y|x), x and y are either max or min of two iid random variables. I don't know either x is max or min, but p = Pr(x=max,y=min)=1-Pr(x=min,y=max)

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

There are two iid random variables $\xi_1,\xi_2 \sim F(\xi)$.

I define two new random variables x and y such that:
$$with~probabitity~p:~~~~~~~~x=max(\xi_1,\xi_2),~y=min(\xi_1,\xi_2)\\
with~probabitity~1-p:~x=min(\xi_1,\xi_2),~y=max(\xi_1,\xi_2)$$

Now let's assume that we observe x. I need to find pdf of y conditional on observed x.

For my goals I need to know this pdf only in the region y>x i.e. I need to find $\tilde{f}(y|x)$ defined as:

$\tilde{f}(y|x)=\mathbb{1}(y>x)\cdot f(y|x), ~~where ~\mathbb{1}(y>x) ~is~ an~indicator~function$

*Note that "in the region y>x" is not the same thing as "conditional on y>x" in these settings.

That's what I got:

$\tilde{f}(y|x)=\mathbb{1}(y>x)\cdot f(y|x)=\\ 
=\mathbb{1}(y>x)\big[f(y|y>x,x)\cdot Pr(y>x|x)+f(y|y<x,x)\cdot Pr(y<x|x)\big] = \\ 
=f(y|y>x,x)\cdot Pr(y>x|x) = f(y|y>x,x)\cdot \frac{Pr(x|y>x)\cdot Pr(y>x)}{Pr(x)} = \\
=f(y|y>x,x)\cdot \frac{Pr(x|y>x)\cdot Pr(y>x)}{Pr(x|y>x)\cdot Pr(y>x)+Pr(x|y<x)\cdot Pr(y<x)}
=\frac{2f(y)F(y)}{1-F^2(x)}\cdot \frac{(1-p)\cdot 2f(x)(1-F(x))}{(1-p)\cdot 2f(x)(1-F(x))+p\cdot 2f(x)F(x)} = \\ =\frac{2f(y)F(y)}{1-F^2(x)}\cdot \frac{(1-p)(1-F(x))}{(1-p)(1-F(x))+pF(x)}$

where the last equality is due to 
$$F_{max(\xi_1,\xi_2)}(\xi)=F^2(\xi),~f_{max(\xi_1,\xi_2)}(\xi)=2f(\xi)F(\xi) \\~F_{min(\xi_1,\xi_2)}(\xi)=1-(1-F(\xi))^2,~~~f_{min(\xi_1,\xi_2)}(\xi)=2f(\xi)(1-F(\xi))$$

Does that look correct? I'm not sure that I didn't make any mistake, so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot have two i.i.d. random variable $\xi_1,\xi_2$ with $\xi_2 >\xi_1$.

Comment: Fair point. But actually I don’t need to assume $\xi_2>\xi_1$. So, I deleted this assumption.